# Step debugging collapses my expanded arrays in Eclipse's Debug View (C++)

Tags: arrays, eclipse, debugging

I've Googled my brains out and can't find this addressed anywhere, so I hope someone here can help me.

I'm coding in C++ using Nsight Eclipse Edition in CentOS Linux 7.1, and whenever I'm step debugging, I've found that every step I take through the code causes my expanded arrays and structs in the Variables View to collapse.  This is very frustrating because I actually AM interested in watching the contents of those arrays and structs.  And it behaves the same way if I try to watch them in the Expressions View.  Has anyone else seen this and found a way to keep those expanded things open?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying, but constantly reloading the array at every step can even more annoying with a large array, so I can see why the decision was made. Try playing around with the "Memory" view and more tightly targeted watch expressions.

Comment: I'm ok with the array reloading at every step, because at the end of the day that means I'll be more productive.  This behavior hasn't always been there.  I know that arrays have stayed open for me before, so I don't understand why it's doing this now.

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same issue I figured out that if I add a Watch on a variable (Right click --> Watch in Variables view), it doesn't collapse or lose focus when stepping. You don't need to switch to the Expressions view to track your variable, just create the watch for it.